# Nextjs <Link> tag goes 404 not found page

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I just created a next.js app then when I try linking another page, it is 404, I read that it is a bug, but I don't know how to fix it. upon creating the app, I don't have the pages folder, I wrote the link on page.js,
[image of the folders, files after you create the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddh1C.png)

```
import Link from 'next/link'
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <><><div>
<Link href='./about'>test</Link> &nbsp;
<Link href={'about'}>ABout</Link> &nbsp;
<a href='/about'>anchor tag</a>
    </div>
    </></>
  )
}
```

what should i do to make it work? thanks

Comment: Is `about.js` present in the `pages` folder?

Comment: yes they are in the same folder

Comment: oh after I install the app, i dont have the page folder, it is in the src/app. The file name of it is page.js

Comment: You have to add `pages` folder and one file for each route. Like `about.js` etc

Comment: I also tried that, i also got 404

Answer (score 0):

I've been saying yes to the src/ in the installation part.
[This solved my problem, I chose no to the 'src/' directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lp5r7.png)